# Convert dates to text in R

Tags: r, list, date, type-conversion

I have the following dataset with dates (YYYY-MM-DD):

```
> dates
 [1] "20180412" "20180424" "20180506" "20180518" "20180530" "20180611" "20180623" "20180705" "20180717" "20180729"
```

I want to convert them in:
DD-MMM-YYYY but with the month being text. For example `20180412` should become `12Apr2018`

Any suggestion on how to proceed?

M

Comment: Checm out `format` and `strptime`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to first *parse* the text strings as `Date` objects, and then *format* these `Date` objects to your liking to have the different text output:

```
R> library(anytime)   ## one easy way to parse dates and times
R> dates <- anydate(c("20180412", "20180424", "20180506", "20180518", "20180530",
+                    "20180611", "20180623", "20180705", "20180717", "20180729"))
R> dates
 [1] "2018-04-12" "2018-04-24" "2018-05-06" "2018-05-18" "2018-05-30"
 [6] "2018-06-11" "2018-06-23" "2018-07-05" "2018-07-17" "2018-07-29"
R> 
R> txtdates <- format(dates, "%d%b%Y")
R> txtdates
 [1] "12Apr2018" "24Apr2018" "06May2018" "18May2018" "30May2018"
 [6] "11Jun2018" "23Jun2018" "05Jul2018" "17Jul2018" "29Jul2018"
R>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try something like this :

```
# print today's date
today <- Sys.Date()
format(today, format="%B %d %Y") "June 20 2007"
```

where The following symbols can be used with the format( ) function to print dates [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEV5o.png)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `as.Date()` and `format()` functions:

```
dts <- c("20180412", "20180424", "20180506", "20180518", "20180530", 
         "20180611", "20180623")

format(as.Date(dts, format = "%Y%m%d"), "%d%b%Y")
```

More information [here](https://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html)

Answer (score 3):

Simply use `as.POSIXct` and `as.format`:

```
dates <- c("20180412", "20180424", "20180506")
format(as.POSIXct(dates, format="%Y%m%d"),format="%d%b%y")
```

Output:

```
[1] "12Apr18" "24Apr18" "06May18"
```